# Iterate over nested List property inside h:datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable, nested

```
    <h:dataTable value="#{SearchingBeans.list}" var="entry">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputLabel>Photo</h:outputLabel>
            </f:facet>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputLabel>Pseudo</h:outputLabel>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{entry.pseudo}"></h:outputLabel>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputLabel>Description</h:outputLabel>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{entry.description}"></h:outputLabel>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputLabel>Photo</h:outputLabel>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{entry.photo[0].path}"></h:outputLabel> <-- this a List
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

i got a entities member one of his property is a List photo  with get/set
that property is populate 
i don't know how to fetch that value in jsf i want only the first picture  for each member since their have 2-3 photos. Its that possible?? any other solution will be appreciate.

Comment: If you have `entry.list` of type `List`, you can check its contents with EL `empty` and then access its first element with `[0]`, if I've got your idea properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just iterate over it using `<ui:repeat>` or `<h:dataTable>` the usual way. It's perfectly valid to nest multiple iterating components in each other. In case of `<h:dataTable>`, you only need to make sure that you put the nested iterating component inside a `<h:column>`.

E.g.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.entities}" var="entity">
    <h:column>
        #{entity.property}
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <ui:repeat value="#{entity.subentities}" var="subentity">
            #{subentity.property}
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

or

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.entities}" var="entity">
    <h:column>
        #{entity.property}
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:dataTable value="#{entity.subentities}" var="subentity">
            <h:column>
                #{subentity.property}
            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

You'll potentially only run into issues when you nest multiple `<ui:repeat>` components and use `<f:ajax>` in it while using an older version of Mojarra.

Only JSTL `<c:forEach>` wouldn't work when nested inside a JSF iterating component for the reasons explained here [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, please don't abuse `<h:outputLabel>` for pure text presentation. It generates a HTML `<label>` element which is intented to [label an input element](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/label/) by `for` attribute. However, you're doing that nowhere in the code. You should be using `<h:outputText>` instead. By the way, I'm lately seeing this more often in code of starters. There must be somewhere a bad tutorial or resource which is abusing the `<h:outputLabel>` this way instead of `<h:outputText>` or even plain EL in template text. Which tutorial/resource was you using? Then I can contact the author about this severe misinstruction. See also [Purpose of the h:outputLabel and its "for" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544141/purpose-of-the-houtputlabel-and-its-for-attribute)

Comment: Tell your teacher to take time apart to learn basic HTML. He clearly knows nothing about HTML semantics.

Comment: @BalusC 'I can contact the author about this severe misinstruction' that's a really great idea. And you're really ingenious about it. Maybe it's one of those notorious JSF-related sites like roseindia?

Comment: How simple it is , but we make it so complicated