# Auto calculated fields

Tags: jsf

I've the following form:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText size="2" value="#{orderMB.quantity}" />
    <h:outputLabel value=" #{orderMB.totalPriceOneItem} €" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" />
</h:form>
```

And I've the following method in a session scoped managed bean:

```
public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
    setTotalPriceOneItem(quantity* item.getItem().getPrice().doubleValue());
}
```

I would like to auto-update the total price result on every key press of the input field. How can I achieve this without pressing the submit button?

Comment: No, i don't submit the button. I want put a quantity in the field and i want that the price is autocalculated. Do you see what i mean ?

Comment: Sorry, i'm new here and i have difficults with english? I'll update my question

Comment: I changed my question. Is it better ?

Comment: I think it ll works, because when a put something in quantity, i call the setter, right ? And in my setter, i have setTotalPriceOneItem who is updated. I thought that like this, the price will be refresh in my view.

Comment: Ok, i'm really bad. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't doing that anywhere. It's missing a `<f:ajax>`.

```
<h:inputText size="2" value="#{orderMB.quantity}">
    <f:ajax event="keyup" render="total" />
</h:inputText>
<h:outputText id="total" value="#{orderMB.totalPriceOneItem} €" />
```

The `event` attribute can be set to any HTML DOM event on which JSF must submit the form by ajax, such as `click`, `keyup`, `blur`, `focus`, etc. The `render` attribute can be set to any JSF client ID which needs to be updated when the ajax submit finishes. In this case it's referring the ID of the component showing total price.

Note that I replaced the [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544141/purpose-of-the-houtputlabel-and-its-for-attribute) `<h:outputLabel>` by `<h:outputText>`. Also noted should be that a setter isn't exactly the right place to perform business logic (a getter also not!). Better revert that setter method to a true setter and add an ajax listener method:

```
<f:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{orderMB.updateTotalPriceOneItem}" render="total" />
```

```java
public void updateTotalPriceOneItem() {
    totalPriceOneItem = quantity * item.getItem().getPrice().doubleValue();
}
```

In case when it still doesn't work, then verify if you have a `<h:head>` in the template instead of a `<head>`. If still in vain, work through [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked).

---

That said, I strongly recommend to take a pause and work through a [sane JSF 2.x book](https://jsf.zeef.com/bauke.scholtz#block_72). The above is usually already covered in the 1st chapter.

Comment: Yes, but i have difficults with english :) I'm not really sur to all understand