# Why plain HTML tags on p:panelGrid represents only one table cell when they are placed sequentially?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

Why plain HTML tags on p:panelGrid represents only one table cell when they are placed sequentially?

Example:

```
<p:panelGrid style="width: 100%" columns="2">
      <h2>VS Luanda-Sul</h2>
      <h2>VS Filda</h2>
      <p:commandButton value="Teste"/>
      <p:commandButton value="Teste"/>
      <p:commandButton value="Teste"/>
      <p:commandButton value="Teste"/>
</p:panelGrid>
```

This shows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I's a very good question.

HTML '' tag is not evaluate like structuring block  of panelGrid.
To do this you need to specify your string as JSF component and it will work

```
                <p:panelGrid style="width: 100%" columns="2">
                    <h:outputText value="VS Luanda-Sul"/>
                    <h:outputText value="VS Filda"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Teste"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Teste"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Teste"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Teste"/>
                </p:panelGrid>
```

For use HTML tags into outputText :

```
                <p:panelGrid style="width: 100%" columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel>                       
                       <h1>VS Luanda-Sul</h1>
                    </p:outputLabel>
                    <p:outputLabel>
                        <h2>VS Luanda-Sol</h2>
                    </p:outputLabel>
                    <p:commandButton value="Teste"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Teste"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Teste"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Teste"/>
                </p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: and create a style class for titles right!?!? This is what i predicted. Thnks

Comment: This answer implies that it's impossible to have plain HTML elements in individual table cells. This is wrong. I'll remove the downvote once you fix the misleading answer.

Comment: you're right and it's not what i want to say. Edited

Comment: It still doesn't show `<h2>` tags in individual cells as OP intented.

Comment: I added a sample to do this :)

Comment: The `<p:outputLabel>` is the wrong component for the job. It generates a HTML `<label>` element. Do you know what it is for? Please stop reading terrible tutorials: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544141/ The answer is just in Java EE tutorial.