# Open file browse panel of p:fileUpload on click of an image

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, graphicimage

Is there any way to fire the basic `<p:fileUpload>` button (the one that shows a panel to select a file) on click of an image?

Comment: For simple html + css, Write the code in a modal..

Comment: When exactly do you want to open it then? On page load?

Comment: onClicking on some picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the image in a label referring the input field.

```
<h:form>
    <p:fileUpload id="file" mode="simple" ... />
    <h:outputLabel for="file">
        <p:graphicImage name="images/pic.png" />
    </h:outputLabel>
</h:form>
```

Do note that this works even if the input is hidden by CSS.

#### See also:

- [Purpose of the h:outputLabel and its "for" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544141/purpose-of-the-houtputlabel-and-its-for-attribute)