# Link does not work in IE but works in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, hyperlink, compatibility

I have a `link` in my JSF 2.2 page which onclick redirects me to a specific page. It works properly in Chrome and Firefox but does not respond in IE. Nothing happens at all.

```
<h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/myPath/stock.jsf" >
        <h:outputLabel value=" Furniture Stock  &amp; Wood " style="cursor: pointer;" />
        <f:param name="stockId" value="#{stockController.stock.stockTye}" ></f:param>
</h:outputLink>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: To exclude one and other, does it work when you disable JavaScript?

Comment: No i just checked that. It doesnt work.

Comment: OK. Next step, create a plain vanilla HTML page with same link. Does it work? (rightclick JSF page in browser and do "View Page Source" to get the HTML to base on).

Comment: No not working. h:outputlink seems to be blank. Is there any alternative for that?

Comment: I didn't mean that. Nevermind, here's another question: what if you put link inside label, or just use h:outputText instead of h:outputLabel (your h:outputLabel doesn't have a "for" attribute which means it isn't labeling anything which implies you was reading bad JSF tutorials, see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/17544141

Comment: Balusc you are genius.. I will make sure to not repeat such mistakes again.. And will surely go through the tutorials today. If you can post this as answer i will accept it :).. Working now.. ThanK YOU :)