# SelectBooleanCheckbox receives focus without mouseover

Tags: jsf, selectbooleancheckbox

I have a weird problem with jsf components (h:inputFile & h:selectBooleanCheckbox).

Both components receive focus, even when my mouse is somewhere else on the page. Here is the code:

```
<h:form id="logoUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div>      
   <h:outputLabel rendered="true">
      <h:inputFile id="companyLogo" label="file" value="#{fileHandlerBean.part}" >
       <f:validator validatorId="FileUploadValidator" />
      </h:inputFile>
   </h:outputLabel>
 </div>

<div class="clear" />

<h:outputLabel rendered="true">
 <div>
   <div style="width: 5%">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="acceptToULogo" value="#{companyEditController.confirmToU}">
     <p:ajax event="change" update="buttonLogo" />
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
 </div>

  <div style="width: 95%">
  <h:outputText value="Some Text " /> 
  </div>
 <br />

<h:commandButton id="buttonLogo" styleClass="formbutton" value="Upload"
      action="#{companyEditController.companyLogoUpload()}" 
      actionListener="#{fileHandlerBean.uploadCompanyLogo()}" 
      disabled="#{!companyEditController.confirmToU}"/>    
 </div>
</h:outputLabel>
</h:form>
```

If I move the mouse over the h:outputText the checkbox receives focus. 
I had the same problem with the h:inputFile tag. I solved it by surrounding it with a h:outputLabel tag, but unfortunately it doesn´t workd with the selectBooleanCheckbox.

Did somebody have the same problem in the past and knows a solution?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17544141 You was most likely reading bad JSF tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because everything is wrapped in the h:outputLabel tag. This outputLable is rendered as a plain label html element.

You can see form the [W3C specification](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) that anything inside the label will toggle the control

> The  element does not render as anything special for the user. However, it provides a usability improvement for mouse users, because if the user clicks on the text within the  element, it toggles the control

To fix this, you need to replace the h:output label tag using a h:panelGroup layout="block" which renders a `<div>`:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="true">
 <div>
   <div style="width: 5%">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="acceptToULogo" >
     <p:ajax event="change" update="buttonLogo" />
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
 </div>

  <div style="width: 95%">
  <h:outputText value="Some Text " /> 
  </div>
 <br />

<h:commandButton id="buttonLogo" styleClass="formbutton" value="Upload"/>    
 </div>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: good suggestion with the panelGroup Balus. This eliminates the extra markup of the html table

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much