# What is the difference between h:outputLabel and h:outputText in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

Oracle source defines h:outputLabel as used to attach a label to an input field. But the next example uses nested h:outputText in it. What is the purpose of using both?

Edit : Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17547333/6086637)

Comment: That question was about h:outputLabel and its for attribute. This one is about h:outputText and its relationship with h:outputLabel.

Comment: Why do you think there is a relation between `h:outputText` and `h:outputLabel`? I'd hope it is clear what an `h:outputText` is and since the duplicate describes the other, you effectively have the 'difference' as requested in your title. And you refer to some oracle text but don't post a link to it. How should we guess then...

Comment: In duplicates, pay attention to the answer, not the question.

Answer (score 0):

The difference lies in the HTML code they generate.

h:outputText is for generic text required anywhere in an HTML page.

h:outputLabel is required to generate the  ...

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544141/purpose-of-the-houtputlabel-and-its-for-attribute) about outputLabel will make the difference between the two clear.